# Failing to request permissions in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Good day.

In all my applications, requesting user permissions is not showing the permissions popup in Android.

I am using the FileSaver in the .NET MAUI CommunityToolkit and as I understand, the `SaveAsync` method is supposed to ask for permission and save to disk.

```
async Task SaveDocument(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    try
    {
        //var fileLocation = await FileSaver.Default.SaveAsync($"{Guid.NewGuid()}.docx", memoryStream, new CancellationToken());
        var someLocation = await FileSaver.SaveAsync($"{Guid.NewGuid()}.docx", memoryStream, new CancellationToken());  
        await Toast.Make($"File is saved: {someLocation}").Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Toast.Make($"File is not saved, {ex.Message}").Show();
    }
}
```

The catch statement is being hit with error message permissions not granted.

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

As such, I thought I would do it using Permission API in .NET MAUI as implemented below

```
public static async Task<bool> CheckForStoragePermission()
{
    bool permitted = false;

    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        permitted = true;
    else
    {
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
    }
    return permitted;
}
```

In both cases, the permissions popup doesn't show up and it moves on with the code.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what Android version is your application targeting ?

Comment: My application is targeting version 21

Comment: You also have to inform Android, in your application manifest, that app will be using permission. This is needed at time app is installed.

Comment: I added that code in the manifest already.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help you if there is any other questions.

Answer (score 5):

I have tested your code on the emulator with the Android 12.0 and Android 11.0. The two devices both worked and will show the the permissions popup.

Did you test your application on the Android 13.0? According to this issue about [.NET MAUI does not work with Android 13 Android.permission.write_external_storage](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11275) on the github. The maui project's default target android framework is Android 13.0(Api 33). And then if you set it on the device which is android 13.0. The storage permission popup will not show because the adnrodi 13.0 has removed this permission.

You can try the workaround in the issue which is adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />` in the **AndroidManifest.xml**. You can also use the device which android version is 12.0 or lower to test your application.

Comment: I want to mark this as the correct answer but since it is a hack, I am not sure I should

Comment: Did you test it on the android 12 or lower? @TanakaMawere